# For loop runs length of array but displays one element array.length times

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, for-loop

I'm working on a project for freeCodeCamp and I'm running a for loop through an array of twitch.tv users. I've created a table and for each username in my array, it's supposed to add the new row, fill it with the data, and move onto the next element. The problem is that every time I run the code it seems to be choosing a random index in the array and running the loop through to equal the number of elements in the array. I think it's a display issue because it's connecting to the server for each individual call.

Hopefully someone can help me out.

```js
var twitch = ['ESL_SC2', 'OgamingSC2', 'cretetion', 'freecodecamp', 'storbeck', 'habathcx', 'RobotCaleb', 'noobs2ninjas', 'ESL_LOL', 'wow_2', 'brunofin', 'comster404']

var streams = 'https://wind-bow.gomix.me/twitch-api/streams/';
var channels = 'https://wind-bow.gomix.me/twitch-api/channels/';
var users = 'https://wind-bow.gomix.me/twitch-api/users/';


var getStream = function(data) {

  if (data.stream === null) {
    $('.status').append('Offline');
  } else {
    var streamStatus = data.stream.channel.status;
    var html = '<td class="stream">' + streamStatus + '</td>';
    $('.stream').html(html);
  }

}
var getChannels = function(data) {
  var game = data.display_name;

  var logoHtml = data.logo;
  var channelUrl = data.url;
  var gameHtml = '<a href=' + channelUrl + ' target="_blank">' + game + '</a>';
  var logoHtml = '<img class="image" src="' + logoHtml + '">';
 
  $('.game').html(gameHtml);
  $('.logo').html(logoHtml);

}


$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.choice').on('click', function() {
    $('.choice').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
  });

  var table = $('<table id="twitch-table"></table>').appendTo('#content');

  for (var i = 0; i < twitch.length; i++) {
    var row = $('<tr></tr>').appendTo(table);
    $('<td class="logo"></td>').appendTo(row);
    $('<td class="game"></td>').appendTo(row);
    $('<td class="stream"></td>').appendTo(row);

    $.getJSON(streams + twitch[i], getStream, 'jsonp');
    $.getJSON(channels + twitch[i], getChannels, 'jsonp');



  }

});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 100%;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#main {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 2% auto 0;
}

#header {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: #116466;
  color: #d1e8e2;
  line-height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0 0 0 5%;
  font-size: 300%;
}

#row {
  background: #285277;
  width: 100%;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.choice {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 33%;
  background: #285277;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #d1e8e2;
  font-size: 150%;
}

.choice a {
  /*padding: 5px 20px;*/
  color: #d1e8e2;
}

#content {
  width: 100%;
  background: #efefef;
}


/*
.choice a:active {
 background: #1E3D59;
}
*/

.selected {
  background: #1E3D59;
}

.selected:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  right: 45%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: solid 10px #1E3D59;
  border-left: solid 10px transparent;
  border-right: solid 10px transparent;
}

table {
  width: 600px;
}

tr {
  margin: 5px 0;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

td {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.game {
  padding-left: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 120%;
  line-height: 75px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.game a {
  color: #111;
}

.image {
  height: 75px;
  width: 75px;
}

.logo {
  padding: 3px 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.stream {
  padding-right: 10px;
  width: 350px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  line-height: 75px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <title>Twitch.tv JSON API</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/57c9bf8971.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id='main'>
    <header id='header'>
      <h1>Twitch Streamers</h1>
    </header>
    <div id='row'>
      <ul>
        <li class='choice selected'><a href='#'>All</a></li>
        <li class='choice'><a href='#'>Online</a></li>
        <li class='choice'><a href='#'>Offline</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id='content'>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: row is declared inside my for loop; first line

Comment: it's only declared inside the for loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in these lines:

```
$('.game').html(gameHtml);
$('.logo').html(logoHtml);
$('.stream').html(html);
```

They select all lines with `game` class (or `logo` or `stream`) And change them all.

See [here](https://jsfiddle.net/d427fs5g/) a fixed JSfiddle.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Thank you. The only issue that I still have is that the first element in the array does not appear. Would you have a solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the callback function properly. Your *getStreams* and *getChannels* functions are applying data to all rows, instead of its own individual row.

Below are the modified callback functions declarations:

```
var getStream = function(url, idx) {
    $.getJSON(url, function(data){
        if (data.stream === null) {
            $('.status').append('Offline');
        } else {
            var streamStatus = data.stream.channel.status;
            var html = '<td class="stream">' + streamStatus + '</td>';
            $('tr').eq(idx).find('.stream').html(html);
        }
    });
}

var getChannels = function(url, idx) {
    $.getJSON(url, function(data){
        var game = data.display_name;
        var logoHtml = data.logo;
        var channelUrl = data.url;
        var gameHtml = '<a href=' + channelUrl + ' target="_blank">' + game + '</a>';
        var logoHtml = '<img class="image" src="' + logoHtml + '">';

        $('tr').eq(idx).find('.game').html(gameHtml);
        $('tr').eq(idx).find('.logo').html(logoHtml);
    });
}
```

And, call them within your `for` loop as:

```
getStream(streams + twitch[i], i);
getChannels(channels + twitch[i], i);
```

JSFiddle for your reference: https://jsfiddle.net/yogesh214/yxLu9mwg/4/

Answer (score 0):

I understand your problem now:

As @Shalom Peles said, you're using `$('.stream')` to select *all* the elements in the document with the class `.stream` instead of just the element within your row.

Instead use `.find` to select within an element. For example:

```
let row = $('<div class="my-row"></div>'); // creates a row
row.append(/* ... */);
let elementInsideRow = row.find('.my-column'); // this selects an element *inside* the row element.
```

Also: [use `let` instead of `var`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21906133/when-should-i-use-let-and-var) for all declarations

---

I edited your code to work for streams. Do the same for channels. Read the comments.

```js
var twitch = ['ESL_SC2', 'OgamingSC2', 'cretetion', 'freecodecamp', 'storbeck', 'habathcx', 'RobotCaleb', 'noobs2ninjas', 'ESL_LOL', 'wow_2', 'brunofin', 'comster404']

var streams = 'https://wind-bow.gomix.me/twitch-api/streams/';
var channels = 'https://wind-bow.gomix.me/twitch-api/channels/';
var users = 'https://wind-bow.gomix.me/twitch-api/users/';

// refactor this like I did below
var getChannels = function(data) {
  var game = data.display_name;

  var logoHtml = data.logo;
  var channelUrl = data.url;
  var gameHtml = '<a href=' + channelUrl + ' target="_blank">' + game + '</a>';
  var logoHtml = '<img class="image" src="' + logoHtml + '">';
 
  $('.game').html(gameHtml);
  $('.logo').html(logoHtml);

}


$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.choice').on('click', function() {
    $('.choice').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
  });

  var table = $('<table id="twitch-table"></table>').appendTo('#content');

  // you need to use `let` here because you need block scope
  // in general, use `let` instead of `var` everywhere.
  // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21906133/when-should-i-use-let-and-var
  for (let i = 0; i < twitch.length; i++) {
    let row = $('<tr></tr>');
    $.getJSON(streams + twitch[i], function(data) {
        
        $('<td class="logo"></td>').appendTo(row);
        $('<td class="game"></td>').appendTo(row);
        $('<td class="stream"></td>').appendTo(row);
        if (data.stream === null) {
            // instead of selecting all the elements with `.status`, use `find` to select *within* the `row` element
            // $('.status').append('Offline');
            row.find('.status').append('Offline');
        } else {
            var streamStatus = data.stream.channel.status;
            var html = '<td class="stream">' + streamStatus + '</td>';
            row.find('.stream').html(html);
        }
        // apend it when you're done
        row.appendTo(table);
    }, 'jsonp');

    // make the same changes for channel
    //$.getJSON(channels + twitch[i], getChannels, 'jsonp');



  }

});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 100%;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#main {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 2% auto 0;
}

#header {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: #116466;
  color: #d1e8e2;
  line-height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0 0 0 5%;
  font-size: 300%;
}

#row {
  background: #285277;
  width: 100%;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.choice {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 33%;
  background: #285277;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #d1e8e2;
  font-size: 150%;
}

.choice a {
  /*padding: 5px 20px;*/
  color: #d1e8e2;
}

#content {
  width: 100%;
  background: #efefef;
}


/*
.choice a:active {
 background: #1E3D59;
}
*/

.selected {
  background: #1E3D59;
}

.selected:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  right: 45%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: solid 10px #1E3D59;
  border-left: solid 10px transparent;
  border-right: solid 10px transparent;
}

table {
  width: 600px;
}

tr {
  margin: 5px 0;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

td {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.game {
  padding-left: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 120%;
  line-height: 75px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.game a {
  color: #111;
}

.image {
  height: 75px;
  width: 75px;
}

.logo {
  padding: 3px 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.stream {
  padding-right: 10px;
  width: 350px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  line-height: 75px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <title>Twitch.tv JSON API</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/57c9bf8971.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id='main'>
    <header id='header'>
      <h1>Twitch Streamers</h1>
    </header>
    <div id='row'>
      <ul>
        <li class='choice selected'><a href='#'>All</a></li>
        <li class='choice'><a href='#'>Online</a></li>
        <li class='choice'><a href='#'>Offline</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id='content'>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```