# push empty array into react's state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

http://jsbin.com/zehoceloka/1/edit

my input number is dynamic, it depends on the API how many data it has. So firstly I map it to the view. But there is also a feature where user can add new item. I trying to push a new empty array, but nothing happens. Am I doing it wrong?

```
class HelloWorldComponent extends React.Component {

  constructor(){
    super()
    this.addNewRow = this.addNewRow.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      "rules":[
        "age must be above 10",
        "must wear shoe"
      ]
    }
  }

  addNewRow(e){
    const updated = this.state.rules.push("");
    this.setState({rules:updated});
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.rules.map(obj => 
           <input type="text" defaultValue={obj} />
         )}
         <button>Add New Rules</button>
         <br /><br />
         <pre>{JSON.stringify(this.state.rules,null,2)}</pre>
       </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to define the click event on button, use this:

```
<button onClick={this.addNewRow}>Add New Rules</button>
```

Few issues in this line:

```
const updated = this.state.rules.push("");
```

1.**Never mutate the state variable** directly by `this.state.a.push()` or `this.state.a = ''`, always use `setState` to update the value.

2.`a.push()` will not return the updated `array`, it will return the value pushed into array.

From [Doc](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#state):

> Never mutate this.state directly, as calling setState() afterwards may
>   replace the mutation you made. Treat this.state as if it were
>   immutable.

Check this working code:

```js
class HelloWorldComponent extends React.Component {
  
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.addNewRow = this.addNewRow.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      rules:[
        "age must be above 10",
        "must wear shoe"
      ]
    }
  }
  
  addNewRow(e){
    let updated = this.state.rules.slice();
    updated.push("");
    this.setState({rules:updated});
  }
    
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.rules.map(obj => 
           <input type="text" defaultValue={obj} />
         )}
         <button onClick={this.addNewRow}>Add New Rules</button>
         <br /><br />
         <pre>{JSON.stringify(this.state.rules,null,2)}</pre>
       </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <HelloWorldComponent />,
  document.getElementById('react_example')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='react_example'/>
```

Comment: shouldnt you use concat() so you dont mutate the state?
`this.setState({rules: this.state.rules.concat(""))}`
or using ES6 destructurring, like this: `this.setState({rules: [...this.state.rules, newState] )}`

Answer (score 1):

The objects in the state cannot be modify, you need to extract them, modify and then add again to the state:

```
addNewRow(e){
  let rules=this.state.rules.slice();
  rules.push('');
  this.setState({rules:rules});
}
```

Comment: can let be var here? why use let here?

Comment: it can be, I just tend to use let: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21906133/when-should-i-use-let-and-var

Comment: I'm afraid yes, React state's objects are immutable, check the related question I added as a comment

Comment: I'm using flux, I can simply change the props. Correct? Or I'm wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this:

```
var arr = this.state.rules.slice();
arr.push("");
this.setState({ rules: arr });
```